# Spinner Adding Items

Tags: android, spinner, addition, items

I have been following the tutorial for adding spinner items to a spinner control for an app. When going into the app, it force closes, and when I comment the code, it works fine, but does not fill the spinner control. Im rather new to the Android world.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,     R.array.spinnerss, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not add after sure.onCreate put below line.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main); // main.xml so replace your xml file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there may be problem due to either:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
```

or this:

```
R.array.spinnerss,
```

Have you defined "spinnerss" actually?

Please check these both the lines, and you should put the Logcat output so that we may catch what exactly the problem?